# how to install a chainguard, when the chainring doesn't have screw holes?

Tags: commuter, chainring, installation

I'd like to install a chainguard like this:

[image: chainguard plus screws]

on a bicycle that's will be spend it fair amount of time commuting, but on closer inspection I see that the largest chainring doesn't have the necessary screw holes, to my surprise (naively enough I assumed this would be "standard").

Also, since this a Hollowtech crankset, using something like this seems to be out of the question as well:

[image: chainguard, centrally fixed]

Is there a way to attach a chainguard to a bike like this, without having to resort to a full-size chainguard?

Comment: Use a drill and install your own holes?  Measure twice, cut(drill) once.

Comment: Thanks @Criggie, but in my case it would be something more like: _"Measure a few times. These numbers do not make any sense, measure again. Drill. Measure again. Drill. Ok, I ***ed up. Let's order a new chainring but with the holes in place anyway"_. :P Was hoping a simpler after-market solution existed for this. Before getting a drill to this chainring I'd probably just order a new one, but with the appropriate screw holes in it. This is less about saving a buck and more about not having to disassemble my crankset. :)

Comment: Fair neough.  Given this ring has the right crank through it, you could stick it on temporarily with superglue or JB weld or sugru.  If it fell off it should still get caught by your pedal/foot and not get lost.    Problem is that's an oily area, and adhesives don't really adhere to greasy bits.  You could use cableties/zip ties but with no clear binding points they tend to slide.   Can't obscure the teeth at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious mounting points for a chainguard are the chainring-spider bolts.

There are many 'bash guards' available that mount like an extra chainring that are intended to protect the chainring teeth, but would probably do just a good a job of keeping pant legs away.

Most are designed for small MTB chairings but larger ones seem to exist with road -bike BCDs. Try googling '50 tooth chainring bashguard'.

Comment: I think that what I was missing was the proper name for the part. This chainring has only 44 teeth, so I guess finding the proper one won't be too difficult. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to modify your chainrings, just tuck your trouser leg into your sock or use [clips](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Silverline-521812-Reflective-Cycling-Trouser/dp/B0082B2SRW/), [velcro bands](https://www.amazon.co.uk/COM-FOUR-reflective-velcro-closure-snapper/dp/B07BRDZDHT/) velcro bands or any of the other similar products on the market. They're cheap, effective and often high-viz and/or reflective.